# How to name class WordPressPost but file wordpress_post.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to know if it's possible somehow declare a file `wordpress_post.rb` that contains the class `WordPressPost` (not following the original naming convention)

Comment: Why not just follow the naming convention and name the file `word_press_post.rb` or change the class name to `WordpressPost`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you use Zeitwerk Mode (default since Rails 6) you can define `'WordPress'` as an acronym.

```
# config/initializers/inflections.rb
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.acronym 'WordPress'
end
```

See: [Autoloading and Reloading Constants (Zeitwerk Mode) - Customizing Inflections](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#customizing-inflections)